# Unable to get user mode networking in QEMU working

Tags: macos, qemu

I am running QEMU-7.0 using Windows 95 guest. Win 95 guest does not acquire 10.0.2.15 IP address from the qemu DHCP server:

[image]

Also, if I switch to static IP addressing with 10.0.2.15/24 and gateway of 10.0.2.2, then I still have no network connectivity (I should at the very least be able to ping 10.0.2.2 [gateway] or 10.0.2.3 [dns] but this does not work).

I invoke qemu like so:

```
qemu-system-i386 -nic user,model=ne2k_isa -hda win95.qcow2 -device sb16 -m 256 -cpu pentium -vga cirrus -soundhw pcspk
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong or how to troubleshoot?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Issue also appears in a Slackware Linux 12.2 guest system using those parameters as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying IRQ 3 for your virtual NIC when you invoke QEMU:

`-nic user,irq=3,model=ne2k_isa`

Alternatively, try following the process described on the [Qemu Windows 95 wiki page](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/GuestOperatingSystems/Windows95#Networking) that shows how to set the IRQ of the NE2000 Compatible interface to `09`. This appears to be the default QEMU uses when you don't specify an `irq` arg with `-nic`.

Comment: Yes, this fixed it. I figured this out awhile back and forgot to update the question.